# Why is my file download from MVC controller returning HTTP 404

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been looking through questions on SO all day but I feel like I'm not getting anywhere here so I turn to the community. Hope you clever folks can help me out.
I've got the following controller action in my project:

```
[HttpGet("export")]
public IActionResult ExportData(string exportType, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime toDate, string search, bool? locked)
{
    // Load the data from the db.
    var data = LoadData(fromDate, toDate, locked, search);
    bytes[] contentBytes = new byte[] { };
    switch (exportType)
    {
        case "csv":
           contentBytes = DataHelpers.ExportDataToCSV(data);
           break;
        // Other cases removed for brevity.
    }
    var content = new MemoryStream(contentBytes);
    return File(content, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Report.csv");
}
```

I'm honestly not sure if the export works because I keep getting an HTTP 404 on my ajax query to it:

```
function dataExport(type) {
    const search = document.getElementById("GridSearch").value;
    const fromDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    const toDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    const locked = document.getElementById("LockedStatus").checked;

    let args = "?exportType=" + type + "&";
    if (search !== null && search.length >= 1) {
        args += "search=" + search + "&";
    }
    if (fromDate !== null && fromDate.length >= 1) {
        args += "fromDate=" + fromDate + "&";
    }
    if (toDate !== null && toDate.length >= 1) {
        args += "toDate=" + toDate + "&";
    }
    if (locked === true || locked === false) {
        args += "locked=" + locked
    }

    if (args.endsWith("&")) {
        args = args.substr(0, args.length - 1);
    }

    // Path is /[area]/[controller]/[action]
    // Url output = /r/OtpLock/export?exportType=csv&search=foo
    $.get("/r/OtpLock/export" + args, null, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I wouldn't have expected a 404 here since it's really just hitting the controller action so I think maybe my routing isn't working?
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    areaName: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Is it the routing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a `[Route(...)]` attribute on the controller that contains the `ExportData` action?

Comment: I do... Currently it's decorated with `[Area("r")]` and `[Route("r/[controller]/[action]")]`

Comment: What is the controller name?

Comment: And isn't `r` in `Route` an extra? Try with `/r/r/OtpLock/export` and see if it works

Comment: Not sure, navigating to `http://localhost:5000/r/OtpLock/Index` works fine (that's the name of the controller... OtpLockController

Comment: So... it still doesn't work with `/r/r/` either

Comment: Based on what you've described, it might work if you swap out `[HttpGet("export")]` for `[ActionName("export")]`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin looks like we've made progress. Please add an answer and explain what I've misunderstood. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a route template of `[Route("r/[controller]/[action]")]` specified on the *controller*, the route for the `ExportData` action becomes:

```
r/OtpLock/ExportData
```

Adding `[HttpGet("export")]` to the `ExportData` method appends an existing segment, `export`, which changes its route to:

```
r/OtpLock/ExportData/export
```

This isn't the URL you're using for your AJAX calls, so the server responds with a 404.

To make this behave as you expect, there are a few options. e.g.:

1. Use `[ActionName("export")]` instead of `[HttpGet("export")]`. This has the effect of providing `export` as the value for `[action]`, rather than the default, which is the name of the method, `ExportData`. It also doesn't add anything extra to the route defined at the controller level.
2. Remove the `[HttpGet("export")]` attribute and rename the `ExportData` action at the code level, by renaming the *method* to `Export` instead of `ExportData`.
3. You might be able to remove both the `[Route(...)]` attribute from the controller and the `[HttpGet(...)]` attribute from the action. This would revert to using convention-based routing, which you've set up with `MapAreaControllerRoute`. This would also require either #1 or #2 above, but I'm not 100% on whether this will work for your setup.